# How to change color of 'focus' on component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Standard color of focus on components in delphi is yellow.

Focus can by active by `TComponent.SetFocus();`, but I dont have any idea how to set up this color.

[image]

Comment: Er, that doesn't look at all standard. You'll have to let us know what your components are. None of my apps ever look like that.

Comment: I have a yellow focus on all components, typical like : `label` ,`button`  to `txdbgrid` etc.

Comment: OK, well I don't. I wonder what is special about your program or your machine.

Comment: I don't see this at all, on any version of Delphi, on either Win7 or Win10 machines. I also don't see it on my Android devices. It's certainly not *standard*.

Comment: In VCL, `TLabel` is a graphical control, not a windowed control, so this cannot be a feature of Windows Accessibility or the like.  There would have to be something extra in the app, maybe a third-party component or something, that is specifically highlighting focused controls.

Comment: @Toster Have you identified what is causing this effect yet?

Comment: Not yet, i loooking for components in Project, mayby something like old seeting of old component.

Comment: @Toster use Microsoft Spy++ or a similar tool in "find window/control" mode. You drag the finder tool, drop it onto your glowing control an it will hopefully display its class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firemonkey you can generate this effect using the GlowEffect. There is an example in the ControlsDemo (if I recall correctly on top of my head) that comes with Delphi.

Comment: I marked this as answer because i have `suiForm` component who add a glow effect.